# Fingerprint reader, Smartcard and SIM module not working on HP Elitebook Folio 9470m with Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: drivers, hp, fingerprint-reader, card-reader, smartcard

Fingerprint Reader, SmartCard and Sim Module aren't working on my HP Elitebook Folio 9470m device. I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10 as instructed, but the issue still remains. I can't even log in now unless selecting *Ubuntu on Xorg*.

```
genius@genius-HP-EliteBook-Folio-9470m:~$ lspci -nn && lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. Centrino Bluetooth Wireless Transceiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05c8:034b Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP HD Webcam [Fixed]
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 138a:003d Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS491
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I found these helpful resources on [Linux Hardware Website](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=1c4f7f2f2a) and from [Rindeal](https://github.com/rindeal/libfprint-vfs_proprietary-driver) on GitHub.

[Same question on the main HP Forum](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/HP-Elitebook-Folio-9470m-fingerprint-smartcard-and-SIM/td-p/8905957). Hopefully, an answer will be posted there.

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Thanks @waltinator

Answer (score 0):

Fingerprint readers are supported in Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur), so upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10 may be all you need to do to solve this issue. And it also includes drivers for other newer hardware.

From the [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-fingerprint.html.en):

> #### Log in with a fingerprint
>
> If your system has a supported fingerprint scanner, you can record
> your fingerprint and use it to log in.
>
> ##### Record a fingerprint
>
> Before you can log in with your fingerprint, you need to record it so
> that the system can use it to identify you.
>
> > Note: If your finger is too dry, you may have difficulty registering your fingerprint. If this happens, moisten your finger slightly, dry
> > it with a clean, lint-free cloth, and retry.
>
> You need [administrator
> privileges](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-admin-explain.html.en)
> to edit user accounts other than your own.
>
> 1. Open the [Activities](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-introduction.html.en#activities)
>    overview and start typing Users.
> 2. Click on *Users* to open the panel.
> 3. Press on *Disabled*, next to *Fingerprint Login* to add a fingerprint for the selected account. If you are adding the
>    fingerprint for a different user, you will first need to *Unlock* the
>    panel.
> 4. Select the finger that you want to use for the fingerprint, then Next.
> 5. Follow the instructions in the dialog and swipe your finger at a *moderate speed* over your fingerprint reader. Once the computer has a good record of your fingerprint, you will see a *Done!* message.
> 6. Select *Next*. You will see a confirmation message that your fingerprint was saved successfully. Select *Close* to finish.
>
> ##### Check that your fingerprint works
>
> Now check that your new fingerprint login works. If you register a
> fingerprint, you still have the option to log in with your password.
>
> 1. Save any open work, and then [log out](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-exit.html.en#logout).
> 2. At the login screen, select your name from the list. The password entry form will appear.
> 3. Instead of typing your password, you should be able to swipe your finger on the fingerprint reader.

Comment: @beastofcaerbannog Thank you for the edit! I'll get better being more thorough with your example. 